# Java Dealing with child Process

Tags: java, process

I have a simple script that writes output to the console using `ProcessBuilder`. And `OutputStreamWriter` see:

[Java Process with Input/Output Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream)

An earlier thread. I believe my problem rests with the fact a sub process is spawned and the initial Parent process is killed. Resulting in the `OutputStreamWriter` to throw a  `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe exception`. Given the application is spawning a second process how can I connect my OutputStreamWriter to this new process? Including being able to read back the output it is generating? Is this even possible in Java? Surly java should be able to follow onto the spawned process.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to read the output of a child of a child ? (where the direct child died ?)

Comment: I run my process which spawns a child. I want to get the output for this new child process and write to it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling [waitFor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) on the process you are running?  That should ensure you're parent doesn't complete before the child.  You may also want to look at [commons exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/), which is an open source library designed to make your life easier when running separate processes in Java.