# why c# console command not running on java?

Tags: c#, java

Can anyone tell me why this c# console command not running on Java?

I've made a C# console program as given below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
namespace face
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String path = args[0];
            byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            Bitmap S1 = new Bitmap(image);
            Console.WriteLine(S1.GetPixel(2, 10));
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `Program.exe image.jpg`, I get:

> Color [A=255, R=128, G=32, B=128]

Then I created a simple Java application to run the `Program.exe` executable:

```
class project 
{   
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    String comman="C:\\WINXP\\system32\\Program.exe Sunset.jpg";
    try 
    {
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comman);
     System.out.println(process.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) 
         {e.printStackTrace(System.err);}
 }
}
```

When I try to run the Java application, I get the following error:

> Program.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It probably cannot find the file "Sunset.jpg". This will cause your C# program to crash.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the working directory? I don't see any error handling in C# to handle a wrong path.

Comment: For a better debugging/diagnostics experience I would start with _not_ naming both executables `Program.exe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to change

```
String comman = "C:\\WINXP\\system32\\Program.exe Sunset.jpg";
```

to

```
String[] comman = { "C:\\WINXP\\system32\\Program.exe", "Sunset.jpg" };
```

Comment: +1. I think it's the best solution, because the C# compiler recognizes the name of image as an element of the array String[] args.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment said, it's probably because the C# program can't open the file: you should specify an absolute path for it, since getting the actual working directory to work right can be an unnecessary pain in this situation. Also it wouldn't hurt to catch exceptions in the C# program (for example for the "no arguments" and "file not found" cases).

Answer (score 0):

The C# process is a child process of the java process, and killed automatically then the java VM terminates. Because the process is started asynchronously, that will happen immediately. If you're interested in the output, replace

```
System.out.println(process.getOutputStream());
```

with (for instance)

```
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
int c;
while ((c = inputStream.read()) >= 0) {
    System.out.print((char) c);
}
```

if not, write

```
process.getInputStream().close();
process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what others have said, I don't think that `System.out.println(process.getOutputStream());` will output what you want here - namely the output of the executed C# executable.

`System.out.println()` has no overload for `OutputStream`, the return type of `Process.getOutputStream()`. So the `System.out.println(Object)` overload will be choosen, which will call `OutputStream.ToString()`, which is not the output of the C# program, but (most likely, bear with me here) the fully qualified typename of the output stream instance.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3643939/21567) SO question/answer, for example, for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check path of exe and image file that you have provided. As I check this code and execute it then I get following output
java.io.BufferedOutputStream@c17164

Here I provide you your modified code

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String path="C:\\C#Sample\\ImageDisplayDemo\\ImageDisplayDemo\\bin\\Debug\\ImageDisplayDemo.exe E:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg";
        try
        {
            Process proc=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
            System.out.println(proc.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```