# writing to terminal from Java

Tags: java, terminal, tty, xterm, pts

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("xterm").start();
```

How can I write and execute commands into this xterm window after the process has been initiated?

In my application I definitely do require executing commands in the same xterm window after it has been initiated.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("xterm", "myArg1", "myArg2").start();
```

See [ProcessBuilder](http://www.oamk.fi/~karil/jdkdoc/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder%28java.lang.String...%29).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot explicitly send keystrokes to any external application, but you can send

initialization parameters, for example- `Notepad "c:\\index.txt"`, `mycmd.exe -i 10 20 24`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can create a process which can be executed from the `Runtime`.

`xterm` is a process such as `ls`, `cat` etc...

You are trying to send instruction to an external process using your Java application, you will only be able to init the application using parameters but I guess it is not enough.

You better use directly Java because you will be able to use the `Process` object which will give you lot of usefull information.