# Java visible command line

Tags: java

I just tried to execute a java command using runtime like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shutdown -s");
```

to shutdown the computer, but I am training on a project that will get both my electronics and computer skills so I want to execute an avrdude command to program the mcu from Java and make a GUI program. So I want the cmd window to be visible when I run the command. I just made it visible by:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start");
```

but I cant write on the window I just created, any help pls????

thanks all

Comment: Google stream redirection for Processes in java, or check out this SO post :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407308/redirect-stdin-and-stdout-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Following would do it for you.

CMD.EXE /K your_command

Comment: i tried to do Runtime.getRuntime().exec("CMD.EXE /K avrdude"); but didn't work did I do anything wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea but still need some help!
What about making a .bat file and running it using java File class
but still when I make a bat file and try to run I get the command multiple times like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4tmZ.png

but all I did was only write avrdude in the bat file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVjb4.png

still need help in that!!

thanks for all answers...

---

***EDIT::***

---

I just looked it up in the internet and figured out a solution which is making a .cmd file instead of a .bat file and that worked great without looping thanks for all the repliers..!! :)