# How to execute c-exe file from java with dynamic input values

Tags: java

Java code to display current output of exe file and wait for input when needed for processing exe, after giving input display new output of the exe file and continue until process ends.

The following is the code that can take entire input needed for exe at a time and then displays entire output.

```
public class ExecuteSampleExe {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("SampleHelloWorld.exe");
        builder = builder.inheritIO();
        Process process = builder.start();      
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit value" + process.exitValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to execute c program from java, same like executing the same c program in console. (waiting for input and displaying output again waiting for input..)

Comment: So you have the C program, you want a Java program that can compile it and then run that program in the terminal?

Comment: No need of compiling , i need only exe file obtained from c file to be executed.

Comment: Check the [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class in Java.

Comment: Yes i tried ,i am able to execute exe file only if i give entire input needed at a time.but i want to give input based on current execution status of exe file.

Comment: A place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407308/redirect-stdin-and-stdout-in-java  particularly the second answer

Comment: Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: I have used same library but i am unable to full fill my requirment