# How to find the program of a process and related dlls by using Java?

Tags: java, dll, process

How can I get all the processes and their respective programs and dlls running in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do that, as Java doesn't have an interface to Windows API. The easiest way I can think of is this:

```
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist /M");
    InputStream is = proc.getInputStream());
    // and now read and parse that long output, listing all processes and DLLs...
```

This does require some work on the parsing, but it saves you from getting out of the Java world.

Comment: Could you give me some link for understanding the process class ?

Comment: @WesleyKhan, it's a standard Java class - see the [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). There's some sample code you can use [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream).