# How can i get processid when i run process in java?

Tags: java

By using the below code i can run batch file

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:/web_chat_temp/RunOpenfire/RunMe.bat");
```

But here how can i get pocess id of this process.

coz i need to stop in other application...

thanks

Comment: Maybe let the subprocess print its pid into stdout?

Comment: check this link -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream

Comment: Don't always rely upon `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. Use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead. Have a look at [this](http://0guzhan.blogspot.in/2011/01/process-builder-demo.html) example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you running this program in windows machine & also you running the other app in windows.

you use the command

> > tasklist  or  tasklist [process name]

to get its process id.