# dx.bat hangs while processing .class files

Tags: android

I'm using dx.bat to prepare my java code and java libraries I'm using for device.  I have several .jar's, and the tool always hangs on the same class.  It doesn't finish or report any errors.  If I remove the .jar that contains that class, then dx.bat completes successfully, but the app won't run, of course, because classes are missing.

The .jar causing problems is aws-android-sdk-1.4.0-core.jar, from Amazon.  The class is com/amazonaws/javax/xml/stream/StaxErrorReporter$1.class

I've searched extensively and found other dx errors, but not this one.  Has anyone else seen this happen?

UPDATE: I'm running dx.bat from a java build tool I made when it hangs.  I tried running the same command from the windows command line, and it runs just fine.  So the problem appears to be with java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the problem was my java code that was running dx.bat.  The issue is explained here:

[Java Process with Input/Output Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream)

I redirected the error stream, and now it's working.