# how to pass parameters to a process during runtime

Tags: java, parameters, process, runtime.exec

I have C code that takes input from the console as,

```
main() {

 int value;
 printf("Enter a value");
 scanf("%d", &value);
 printf("the value is, %d", value);
 return;
}
```

now I compile and create an .exe file. (say test.exe)

After that I want to call that executable file from a java code.

so, I used

```
public class JavaTest {
static String s=null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException {

    java.lang.Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();


    System.out.println("start");
    java.lang.Process p = rt.exec("test.exe");

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));


    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    p.waitFor();

    System.out.println("done.");
 }
}
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. My question is, how do I pass the integer to the process during runtime? I don't want to pass it as command line parameter.

Comment: It's the latest one, jdk 7

Comment: See accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream

Answer (score 0):

use the outputStream before you use the inputStream of the Process. Write the integer to the output.Stream

Comment: do I write this?   int a=1;   BufferedWriter stdOut = new BufferedWriter(new 
                OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        
        stdOut.write(a);