# How can I wait for a subprocess to complete in a process in Java?

Tags: java, shell, command-line, cmd

this is basically what I am trying to do: I created a `Process` that simulates the command line. Like this:

```
private Process getProcess() {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe");
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = builder.start();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return p;
}
```

Now I can "feed" this process with commands:

```
BufferedWriter p_stdin = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
try {
            p_stdin.write("dir"); // Just a sample command
            p_stdin.newLine();
            p_stdin.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed to run " + fileName;
        }
```

What I now would like to do is wait for the command, that is the subprocess of my process, to complete. How can I do that? I know that I can wait for processes with the `waitFor()` method, but what about a subprocess??

Comment: Does [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3644288/) help?  (It uses `/bin/bash`, but you should be able to replace that with `cmd.exe`.)

Answer (score 1):

The `dir` command is not a subprocess, it is executed internal to `cmd`. However, this is not much relevant, anyway: from the perspective of Java any other command, which is launched in a subprocess, would behave the same.

To wait for the `dir` command to complete you must interpret the incoming stdout output from `cmd` and realize when the prompt was printed again. This is a quite brittle mechanism, though.

In any case, you currently don't consume `cmd`'s stdout at all, which will cause it to block soon, never recovering.