# Does Runtime.exec() allow user input?

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

This is the scenario I'm trying to achieve using Java API 
function: [getRuntime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

I have a sample python script, in the script after some functionality check, it require's some input from the user, this script I want to execute using `getRuntime().exec()` method. I know we can give command line arguments to the script through `getRuntime().exec()` method, but I'm not sure if the above scenario is possible using `getRuntime().exec()` method.

Is it possible to do it, please let me know?

Comment: Tip:  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime.exec() gives you a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). you can read and write to that Process (using getOutputStream() and getInputStream(), which allows you to get what's output by your script and send it more information afterwards. See for example [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream).