# scala sys.process how to enter input?

Tags: scala

in scala I run

```
val result = Process("kinit user@SOMETHING.COM")
```

which then expects an input

```
Password for user@SOMETHING.COM:
```

is there a way for me to enter it from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work with input and output from a process you need to open it so that you can get the `STDIN` and `STDOUT` streams. A good example can be found in the question[Java Process with Input/Output Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream). This is still pretty painful, if you are trying to automate some code that requires input on prompts.

In unix this is traditionally handled with the [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) library, and fortunately, there is a java port of it on github as [Expect4J](https://github.com/cverges/expect4j). Using Expect4J, you still start the process the same way and get it's input and output streams, but then feed those to Expect4J and program your interaction from there:

```
val expect = new Expect4j(process.getInputStream(), process.getOutputStream())
expect.expect("Password for user@SOMETHING.COM:")
expect.send(password)
```

Comment: Not to nitpick but if you start the process the same way you get a "value getInputStream is not a member of scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder"