# Java redirect input and output stream

Tags: java, stream, processbuilder

To excecute [SENNA](http://ml.nec-labs.com/senna/) in the terminal I use the command:

```
senna.exe < input.txt > result.txt
```

Now I want to realize this in a java program. This is my code so far

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("senna.exe");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

writer.write("This is a test sentence");;
writer.flush();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
    System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
}
```

To redirect the input, output and error stream I used the code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream). The problem is that I get the following error message:

> FATAL ERROR: unable to open file hash/words.lst

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the examples you've given it seems that you're adapting Linux code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream) to run on Windows with senna.exe.

From the error you're getting it seems that you forgot to change Linux's forward slash (/) to Windows' backslash (\).

Try changing your filepath's forwardslash to backslash.

Comment: I have checked th filepaths but it is not the reason for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you haven't set the directory path to ProcessBuilder object. This error seems to be because there is a folder called 'hash' in senna folder which can't be reached.

Please try this:
    builder.directory(new File("/yourpathtosenna/senna/")); (I am on a linux machine)

Your error should most probably change, but I am not sure if you will get the output as I am also struggling with running senna interactively through Java on a Linux machine at the moment.

Good luck and do update if you are successful!