# Java exec stdin not flushing

Tags: java, bash, unix

For a school project I am trying to create a terminal in Java. The terminal works in the following way:

1. User types a command
2. Program grabs command and replaces `<command>` with the command in the string

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "cd current/directory/; <command>; echo kjsfdjkadhlga; pwd
   ```
3. Program starts the process created via a `ProcessBuilder` object
4. Program spawns a thread that reads from stdout and stderr
5. Program continues looking for user input, and if the command is done running, then whatever the user entered is run as a command, otherwise it is fed to the currently running command as input.
6. As output is generated, program looks through the output for the `kjsfdjkadhlga` string so it knows when the user's command is done being run, and then grabs the remaining output and stores it as the current path that the user is at.

### How this works/reasons for everything:

In order to avoid myself having to implement my own input parser to handle things like multiple commands on a line, IO redirection, and whatnot to work with the `ProcessBuilder`, I just essentially convert the command to a bash script and let bash execute it.

Since every process executes only a single command (or whatever it was given at the time of creation, which is a single user command in this case) then terminates, no process specific information is stored, such as the current working directory. To transfer that information, I call pwd after the user's command and then in the process of the next command, but before the user's command is run, I `cd` to that directory, effectively allowing the value of `$PWD` to persist between processes.

### The Problem:

It all works well, except for when user interaction is required. If the user just types `cat`, it is supposed to wait for a line of user input, then print it, then wait for a line of user input, then print it, and repeat forever (I don't handle <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> yet...). However, what actually happens is that the terminal waits for a line of user input, then prints it, then terminates without waiting for more input.

### What I have tried:

Currently, I provide input to the command being run with:

```
 BufferedWriter stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
 stdin.write(input);
 stdin.newLine();
 stdin.close();
```

If instead of calling `close()`, I call `flush()`, then `cat` ends up waiting for user input and not doing anything until I terminate my Terminal program, at which point it then prints everything the user had input.

It appears that the `flush()` function doesn't actually do anything. A Stack Overflow question mentioned using the raw `OutputStream` and calling `write()` instead of using a `BufferedWriter`. However, that has the same effect. In the `OutputStream` documentation for `flush()`, it states that "The flush method of `OutputStream` does nothing."

I have also tried using a `BufferedOutputStream`, but the documentation says that its `flush` function simply forces the buffered data to be written to the underlying `OutputStream`, which doesn't change the fact that the `OutputStream` is not flushing *its* stream.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream) question seems to be the most promising, but I couldn't get it to work when implementing it. It may be because I am on Mac OS instead of Windows.

Does anybody know how to do this if keeping stdin open long enough to submit multiple lines of input is possible, or if I am going about it wrong?

---

## Code

#### main()

```
Terminal terminal = new Terminal();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

while (in.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = in.nextLine();
    terminal.sendInput(line, terminal);
}
```

#### terminal.sendInput() called by main

```
// ProcessReaderDelegate implements functions called when receiving output on stdout, stderr, and when the process terminates.
public int sendInput(String text, ProcessReaderDelegate delegate)
{
    if (processes.size() > 0)
    {
        processes.get(0).sendInput(text);  // Is a ProcessReader object
        return 1;
    }

    run(text, delegate);   // runs the given text as the <command> text described above
    return 2;
}
```

#### ProcessReader's sendInput() called by terminal.sendInput()

```
public boolean sendInput(String input)
{
    try
    {
        // stdin and process are a instance fields
        // tried this and doesn't seem to work (with either flush or close)
        stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
        stdin.write(input);
        stdin.newLine();
        stdin.close();

        // tried this and doesn't seem to work (with either flush or close)
        //BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        //os.write(input.getBytes());
        //os.write("\n".getBytes());
        //os.flush();
        //os.close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: this should never happen: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### terminal.run() called by terminal.sendInput()

```
public void run(String command, ProcessReaderDelegate delegate)
{
    // don't do anything with empty command since it screws up the command concatentaion later
    if (command.equals(""))
    {
        delegate.receivedOutput(null, prompt);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        // create the command
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(shellPath);
        list.add(UNIX_BASED ? "-c" : "Command : ");

        String cmd = (UNIX_BASED ? getUnixCommand(command) : getWindowsCommand(command));
        list.add(cmd);
        //System.out.println("command='" + list.get(0) + " " + list.get(1) + " " + list.get(2) + "'");

        // create the process and run it
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(list);
        Process p = builder.start();
        ProcessReader stdout = new ProcessReader(p, delegate, this);
        new Thread(stdout).start();

        processes.add(stdout);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

#### ProcessReader.run() executed in thread and reads stdout and stderr

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        boolean hitend = false;
        String buffer = "";

        while (true)
        {
            int c;
            String text;

            // ======================================================
            // read from stdout
            // read the next character
            c = stdout.read();

            // build the string
            while (c != -1)     // while data available in the stream
            {
                buffer += (char)c;
                c = stdout.read();
            }

            // send the string to the delegate
            if ((!hitend) && (buffer.length() > 0))
            {
                // END_STRING is the "kjsfdjkadhlga" echoed after the command executes
                int index = buffer.indexOf(END_STRING);

                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    hitend = true;
                    text = buffer.substring(0, index);
                    buffer = buffer.substring(index + END_STRING.length());

                    if (outputDelegate != null)
                    {
                        outputDelegate.receivedOutput(process, text);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = END_STRING.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        index = buffer.indexOf(END_STRING.substring(0, i));

                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            index = buffer.length();
                        }

                        if (index >= 0)
                        {
                            text = buffer.substring(0, index);
                            buffer = buffer.substring(index + i);

                            if (outputDelegate != null)
                            {
                                outputDelegate.receivedOutput(process, text);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // ======================================================
            // read from stderr
            // read the next character
            c = stderr.read();
            text = "";      // slow method; make faster with array

            // build the string
            while (c != -1)     // while data available in the stream
            {
                text += (char)c;
                c = stderr.read();
            }

            // send the string to the delegate
            if ((text.length() > 0) && (outputDelegate != null))
            {
                outputDelegate.receivedError(process, text);
            }

            // ======================================================
            // check if the process is done (and hence no more output)
            boolean done = false;

            try
            {
                int value = process.exitValue();
                done = true;        // if got to this point, then process is done

                // read the ending environment variables
                Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String[] words = buffer.split(" ");

                env.put(ENV_WORKING_DIR, words[0]);

                if (envDelegate != null)
                {
                    envDelegate.processTerminatedWithEnvironment(process, env);
                }

                // end the process
                outputDelegate.processEnded(process);
                stdout.close();
                stderr.close();

                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}   // no exit value --> process not done

            if (done)   // just on the off chance that closing the streams crashes everything
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR: ProcessReader: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: `OutputStream.flush()` does nothing because there is no buffer to flush. `BufferedOutputStream.flush()` flushes its buffer. Your problem appears to have more to do with the behaviour of `cat` than of Java. You shouldn't close the output stream if you plan to write further to it. You are going to have to post some code.

Comment: @EJP I agree with the idea that I shouldn't close the output stream if I want to continue writing. However, closing it seems to be the only way to get `cat` to process the current input and produce output. That is the question: how to leave the output stream open and get the process to consume the input.