# Java reader does not start printing until closing the programm

Tags: java, java-io

Loop doesn t start printing until i m closing the program.I tried everything to bring it working but nothing helps.
The Shell script is running a python Script which prints in line format.
**This ([Java Process with Input/Output Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream)) post is a completely different theme.**

```
package de.ye.car_gps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GET_SEND_GPS implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/pi/st_gps.sh");
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new                   InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while (true) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            THREAD_GPS.writer.println(line);
            THREAD_GPS.writer.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your shell script probably doesn't write lines to its stdout. What does it do?

Comment: I only find results which do it like i..

Comment: JB Nize It runs a python Script.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream