# run perl script by command line using java and some cmd operator

Tags: java, perl

I'm trying to run a perl scripts using this java code:

```
ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder("perl","test.pl","test.txt","|", "test1.pl",">","result.txt");
```

So the first script reads a `txt` file and then print some result.

Then the second script get this output, does some others modifications, and then prints them in a new txt file `result.txt`

This command line works fine using `cmd` on windows, but when using java, there is a problem with the `|` and the `>`.

Is there a way to run a such command using java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the piping using ">" simply doesn't work (when you make those java "process" calls).

What you have to do instead: when creating such a process, you can (programmitically) acquire its input and output streams.

So instead of doing a piped command, you just do

```
perl test.pl
```

and your **java** code then has to read from stdout of that process and write that content into a file; or in your case, write it into the stdin of another process call that runs your second script.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream) on how to do that.

Alternatively, you could enhance your perl scripts to take a file name argument, so that you could call it like

```
perl test.pl --write-to tmp.txt
perl test1.pl --read-from tmp.txt --write-to test.txt
```

for example. Then your java side can make both calls in one shot.