# Trying to show the execution of bat file in eclipse console

Tags: java

```
public class Sonar {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String sonarpath=System.getenv("Sonar");
        sonarpath=sonarpath.replace("\\","\\\\");
        String[] command={sonarpath+"\\StartSonar.bat"};

        try {
            Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
            int i=0;
            while((i=in.read())!=-1){
                System.out.print((char)i);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Trying to display the execution of sonar.bat file in eclipse console through this program. But it is not showing anything in the console and there are no errors also . I have searched on the  web, but couldn't find anything useful
It seems it is not entering into while loop, because i tried to print some string, it was not printing that also. I am not able to figure out the problem
i have ran the .bat without opening the cmd before it is possible, and one of my bat is working fine in the console and i do not want to open a cmd

Comment: check what is being printed in the error stream

Comment: already done that, still it is showing nothing

Comment: You can't run `.bat` file directly. You must use `cmd.exe /c xxx.bat`.

Comment: i have ran the .bat without opening the cmd before it is possible, and one of my bat is working fine in the console and i do not want to open a cmd

Comment: please do not mark anything duplicate without proper knowledge@Andreas

Comment: @AvinashTiwari, you may want to look into this answer, which shows how to redirect streams properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643939/java-process-with-input-output-stream

Comment: still couldn't get the output in console