# Can I create a JHipster application through a java code?

Tags: java, jhipster, code-generation

I want to generate a JHipster application programmatically.

Is there an API in Jhipster to which I can pass all the parameters that are required (when I generate the app in the CLI, I pass several parameters one after the other), and get the application generated?

It would be great if I could save the parameters required in a file in somewhere, and then call the Jhipster application generation API and get the application generated.

Comment: you can probably control the cli commands via java exec: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3643939/995891 (and hope it doesn't require interactive keyboard input from a terminal). There is no other api afaik

Comment: Thanks zapl, I could not find an API either, but I think it would be a nice thing to have. Specially when we are generating multiple applications with Jhipster, it is time consuming and difficult to go through the CLI every time.

Comment: Why don't you use the JDL to generate your apps? https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#applicationdeclaration

Comment: This helped, thanks! I was not aware that I could use the JDL to generate apps, I was using them to only create the entities. @GaëlMarziou

Answer (score 2):

Jhipster writes all your chosen settings in the .yo-rc.json file so you could generate it yourself with the desired parameters and then call JHipster - it will detect it and generate everything accordingly

There's probably a better way but this should work for Windows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dir = "path/to/dir";
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"generator-jhipster\": {\n" +
                "<your settings>" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(dir + ".yo-rc.json");
        out.println(json);
        out.close();
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"" + dir + "\" && jhipster");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) { break; }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Evertude, How do I call Jhipster? as a system command? if so how do I pass the location of the .yo-rc.json file?

Comment: JHipster is automatically searching for a .yo-rc.json file in the directory from which it is called. Added some sample code for you